# Install GParted on a mac with Homebrew or Macports?

Tags: macos, partitioning, gparted, homebrew, macports

I'd like to install Gparted on my mac, and I thought I could use Homebrew or Macports to help with that, but I can't seem to figure it out. I tried using Homebrew because I haven't really heard good things about Macports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot install GParted on Mac OSX. You will have to use the [Live Version](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/gparted/gparted-live-0.21.0-1-i586.iso). This is according to the GParted [website](http://gparted.org/index.php) itself.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image: GParted Requirements]

You can definitely find GParted alternatives for Mac OSX [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/gparted/?platform=mac). I found something interesting [here](http://www.chris3000.com/projects/expand-raspberry-pi-root-partition-with-macbook-pro/), that parted does not even compile for Mac OSX.

Comment: Btw, the Ubuntu site has a nice guide about how to create a bootable USB stick from an .iso image on OS X: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: This answer would be even more usefull if somebody could add the proper way of creating a bootable USB with Gparted Live for booting on Mac.

Comment: @Ben use the command sudo dd if=gparted.iso of=/dev/your_usb_drive

Comment: @aliasgar that approach didn't work for me; I don't know why. It's possible the device doesn't have a GPT partition table and that the Mac disk utility isn't creating a GPT table even when I format the device with Mac's own HFS file system; possibly some other utility is required to explicitly give the device a GPT partition table first.

Comment: EDIT: I see that if I select the device in disk manager (not the partition) I can change the partition type to GUID (GPT). I'll report back if I have any luck.

Comment: As of today the website indicates that MacOS is supported

Comment: @mreff555: Today also it doesn't. It quotes "Mac OS X by booting from media containing GParted Live."

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Docker is a possibility for you. I found [Docker-PiShrink](https://github.com/thhan/Docker-PiShrink), it can create a docker service for gparted.

> Docker-Image to shrink your Pi-Image in Docker without VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Although GParted is not available for macOS, I was able to access my flash drive as a raw disk in GParted easily by using the [GParted Live bootable image](https://gparted.org/download.php) in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) and [creating a raw disk image from my flash drive](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#rawdisk) with the device file retrieved using `diskutil list` (`/dev/disk2` in my case). Both `VBoxManage` 
and `VirtualBox` must be run as sudo from a command line, and the flash drive must be unmounted before the virtual machine will launch.